# How to pass parameter to DELETE in AngularJS?

Tags: c#, angularjs, http

Which is the right way to pass parameter in a DELETE in AngularJS?

This call is not working:

```
 $http.delete("api/testDelete",
             { 
              Id:5
             }
             ).success(function (data) {
                alert('Exit status ' + data);
            });
```

This call is working:

```
  $http.delete("api/testDelete",
             { 
               { params: { Id: 5 } }
             }
             ).success(function (data) {
                alert('Exit status ' + data);
            });
```

This is the C# Web Api being called:

```
[HttpDelete]   
  public bool testDelete(int Id)
  { return true; }
```

Why do i have to use params?
Is it possible to pass an object?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send params to the api in two ways:

- **In the query string:**

  ```
  $http.delete("api/testDelete",{ 
       { params: { Id: 5 } }
   }).success(function (data) {
       alert('Exit status ' + data);
   });
  ```
- **In the body of the request:**

  ```
   $http.delete("api/testDelete",{ 
       { data: { Id: 5 } }
   }).success(function (data) {
       alert('Exit status ' + data);
   });
  ```

Answer (score 2):

You need to send the id in the URL:

```
$http.delete("api/testDelete/5")
     .success(function (data) {
        alert('Exit status ' + data);
     });
```